# SPARK SQL select from group by select result

Tags: sql, select, nested, apache-spark-sql

I have a table which is called table_new.
In the first step I would like to group by the results by id, kmstand, vacationname and vacationvalue where only one count exists for each of the group by. For this step, I have already created a query:

```
SELECT id, kmstand, vacationame, vacationvalue 
 FROM `db_1`.`table_new` 
 WHERE (vacationame='vacation1' 
    OR vacationame='vacation2' 
    OR vacationame='vacation3' 
    OR vacationame='vacation4') 
 GROUP BY id, kmstand, vacationame, vacationvalue 
 HAVING COUNT(*) = 1 ORDER BY id, kmstand DESC
```

The result is:

```
    id  kmstand vacationame vacationvalue
1   1   4000    vacation1   munich
2   1   4000    vacation1   stuttgart
3   1   5500    vacation4   koln
4   1   5500    vacation2   frankfurt
5   1   5500    vacation3   berlin
6   1   5500    vacation1   potsdam
7   2   6000    vacation2   new york
8   2   6000    vacation1   bangladesh
9   2   3000    vacation1   washington
10  2   3000    vacation3   chicago
```

Now, I would like to select the id where the combination kmstand and vacationname is now distinct. This means the result should be:

```
        id  kmstand vacationame vacationvalue
1   1   5500    vacation4   koln
2   1   5500    vacation2   frankfurt
3   1   5500    vacation3   berlin
4   1   5500    vacation1   potsdam
5   2   6000    vacation2   new york
6   2   6000    vacation1   bangladesh
7   2   3000    vacation1   washington
8   2   3000    vacation3   chicago
```

For this, I have created the following nested sql query:

```
    SELECT id, kmstand, count(*) as cnt 
FROM `db_1`.`table_new`
WHERE (SELECT id, kmstand, vacationame, vacationvalue 
     FROM `db_1`.`table_new` 
     WHERE (vacationame='vacation1' 
        OR vacationame='vacation2' 
        OR vacationame='vacation3' 
        OR vacationame='vacation4') 
     GROUP BY id, kmstand, vacationame, vacationvalue 
     HAVING COUNT(*) = 1 ORDER BY id, kmstand DESC) 
GROUP BY id, kmstand 
HAVING cnt = 1 
ORDER BY id, kmstand DESC
```

I tried it also without the where clause or without from and didn't find a solution. For this SQL query I get the following error message: `org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot recognize input near 'SELECT' 'id' ',' in expression specification; line 3 pos 7`
I am pretty sure, that the syntax is not right. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the answer for the question. Now here I am able to get the ids where the combination id, kmstand and vacationame is distinct.

```
SELECT id, sumcnt, cnt2
    FROM(
        SELECT id, count(*) as cnt2, sum(cnt) as sumcnt
        FROM (
            SELECT id, kmstand, vacationame, count(*) as cnt
            FROM `db_1`.`table_new` 
            WHERE (vacationame='vacation1'
                OR vacationame='vacation2'
                OR vacationame='vacation3'
                OR vacationame='vacation4')
            GROUP BY id, kmstand, vacationame)T
        GROUP BY id)T
    WHERE (sumcnt/cnt2 = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with SPARK, but you probably want:

```
SELECT id, kmstand, count(*) as cnt 
FROM (SELECT id, kmstand, vacationame, vacationvalue 
     FROM `db_1`.`table_new` 
     WHERE (vacationame='vacation1' 
        OR vacationame='vacation2' 
        OR vacationame='vacation3' 
        OR vacationame='vacation4') 
     GROUP BY id, kmstand, vacationame, vacationvalue 
     HAVING COUNT(*) = 1) T
GROUP BY id, kmstand 
HAVING cnt = 1 
ORDER BY id, kmstand DESC
```

Note that I added an alias (`T`) for the table in the FROM clause.  This may or may not be required, depending on your RDBMS.

Also note that you generally can't ORDER BY in a subquery.

Comment: The problem with your query is that is not filter out results where vacationame occurs more than one time per id. The result should be that only ids with only non duplicated vacationame are available.

Comment: I thought about that we can use something like: where all cnt for an id is 1